# Which is the best way to make config changes in conf files in ansible

Tags: linux, makefile, ansible

Initially I used a `makefile` to deploy my application in `linux`.

I had various `sed` commands to replace variables like the PHP upload file size, post size, log file location etc.

Now I am shifting to ansible. I know I can copy the files, but how can I make changes to the conf files? Like if i just want to change the `upload_filesize = 50M` parameter. I don't want to make copies of the whole conf file and then replace with my file.

Sometimes it’s only a one-line change. Is there any better way to edit the config files in ansible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's an INI file, then your specific requirements can be probably met by `ini_file` module (http://docs.ansible.com/ini_file_module.html).

If your change is limited just few lines (or eve one), then you can probably look at `lineinfile` module (http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html).

Should you however need to change large number of settings, then it may be more beneficial to use `template` (http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html) or `assemble` (http://docs.ansible.com/assemble_module.html). The main disadvantage of this approach is that you may need to review your template or fragments when updating your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operating system, you can add files here /etc/php/apache2/conf.d/10-someinifilewithsetting.ini