# Section aware edits to config files without complicated regex

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for a robust way to edit existing config files with ansible.

In the example below I want to change the value of `key`in `[right_section]` or add it if it doesn't exist at all:

```
[wrong_section]
key = value

[right_section]
wrong_key = value
# key = value
key = wrong_value
wrong_key = value

# [right_section]
# key = value
```

I can't figure out a good way to do this with lineinfile or replace without using overly complex regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ini_file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ini_file_module.html) module.

Example from documentation:

```
# Ensure "fav=lemonade is in section "[drinks]" in specified file
- ini_file: dest=/etc/conf section=drinks option=fav value=lemonade mode=0600 backup=yes
```

Comment: Thank you! Shame on me for not finding it myself and for missing this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339832/which-is-the-best-way-to-make-config-changes-in-conf-files-in-ansible/22342331#22342331
I think my question should be flagged as a duplicate.